# Managing app updates in play store (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services, updates

hello there i want to ask about updating flutter app in play store 
for example if i have a flutter app already published in play store and i have done some changes on it and now i have uploaded it to play store as an update.

so the question is :

1 - how may i notify the user that there is an update for my app ?

2 - and if i have unpublished app and i want to add links like rate my app and links related to my app in play store (it is unpublished yet) how can i get these links so that i may put them in my application before releasing it in play store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you have to implement a custom solution for each case you asking about.

For example, to notify users you can:

1. Send push notifications to app users with information about an update being available. Clicking on such notification should lead to Play Market page with your application presented.
2. Or you can implement one more API route to your backend from which your app will request information about updates, e.g. a text file with the latest version of your app available. That version can be compared to the version of the application installed. If the new version is higher - show a popup notifying a user about the new update.

What relates to having links in your app that lead to the store page of your app - I think the second option I described above will also handle this issue. Custom API that returns a link in simple text format that if not empty could be opened. If you are just trying to avoid additional update - this solution will work.

Comment: great thanks a lot , i thought there is some magical way (some feature from the store itself) to do what i need but obviously there isn't , i should do it the old fashion way

Answer (score 0):

Use the flutter package `upgrader`. will serve you well